# weird DNS resolution problem

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, ip-address

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, all updates. I encounter a consistent DNS resolution problem with exactly ONE web address, namely that of my university. It occurs when the following conditions are met:

1. [go to university, and connect from within via the universities WLAN, which requires my username + password] update: ok it just happened without going to university - just going to bed and waking up again
2. put my laptop to sleep and go home
3. Start the laptop, plugin LAN cable which connects via my standard home router

At this point internet works well, except DNS resolution of my universities website, which fails / times out. Everything else resolves fine.

What **doesnt** help: Flushing DNS caches, disabling wlan

What **DOES** help: 'sudo service network-manager restart'

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

edit: So after I woke up this morning and turning my laptop on from sleep mode - promptly the dns resolution fails! So it seems it's not related to my university WLAN network or something.

edit: add requested data

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 11  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search home my-uni.edu xy.my-uni.edu

$ systemd-resolve --status

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: [ipv6-of-my-uni]
                      [another ipv6-of-my-uni]
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      my-uni.edu
                      xy.my-uni.edu

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      home
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `systemd-resolve --status`.

Comment: @heynnema done. well that is strange. why are there dns servers of my uni there!? I didnt add any. Only thing I can think of is that I used an openvpn profile of the uni once to connect to their network.

Comment: I assume that you're required to use an OpenVPN connection when connected to the uni wlan, yes? How are you connecting... via CLI or NM GUI? When at the uni, and you sleep your computer, it still thinks there's a wlan out there. You should try disconnecting the VPN so there's no defined tap/tun device, and then disconnect the wlan. Installing this might help... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/904/disconnect-wifi/